# How to use the chrome browsing data javascript api?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In chrome browser, I want to have a javascript method to delete indexed db cache and the resource cache (which stores like js/css/cookies). I found this page
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData

Also if possible I want to delete the files if it came from a certain domain like http://myserver

But does anyone know how to write the code with the right settings to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Chrome JavaScript APIs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index) are available to Chrome Extensions. You won't have access to the API functions from normal web page scopes.

There are various guides online for [Getting started with Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted). There are three basic things you need here:

1. A manifest file for the app. You need to specify the `browsingData` permission to use the [chrome.browsingData](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browsingData) API you found.
2. A `popup.html` page, which loads a `popup.js` script file. This should be referenced as the default popup in the manifest file (see the guide link above).
3. In the `popup.js` file, call `chrome.browsingData.remove` with the removal options you require, as the `options` object, and callback function, which could simply be a `console.log` to confirm the data has been removed (it's not instant).

As well as the guide above and the API docs, there's an [Extension Samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:browsingdata) page providing small example extensions to download. You can unpack them straight into Chrome to get started.

To answer your second question, there doesn't appear to be an option for deleting browsing data related to a particular domain or schema at this time.

## Update based on comments

Since you are not using Chrome Extensions, you will have to use the native APIs and other techniques to handle cached resources.

For IndexedDB, you can remove/clear the database for your particular domain. See the [IndexedDB API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) for how to do that.

For resources, such as images, css and JS, use cache busting techniques. This is where you append a timestamp or hash to the end of the resources you are serving. This will prevent the browser from re-using the same resource in the cache. It won't clear the cache, but it will just not re-use the old resources.

You can use the `Cache-Control` header too:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
```

Expire cookies by setting them to a past date.

Comment: In my case i am not using extensions, so does that mean I can't use this at all?

Comment: @omega How were you thinking of using it? Can you imagine if any website's JS could just call `chrome.browsingData.remove(...)` and delete all their visitor's history?

Comment: I was thinking the same logic as CORS. Only delete if it originated from same domain.

Comment: You'll have to use the individual APIs. In your case, you can delete the IndexedDB database for your domain. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API. For old resources, use cache busting techniques, etc.

Comment: What's a cache busting technique?

Comment: The resources (images, css, js, etc.) you serve can have a timestamp (or hash) appended to the end. This prevents the browser from re-using the cached data because it will not find the exact same path in the cache.

Answer (score 1):

**Cookies**

For your domain can be deleted using pure javascript

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

**JS/CSS files**

Append timestamp to the js/css URLs so that every url is unique and hence, caching won't work.
https://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/

**IndexedDB** (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)

```
function clearObjectStore(store_name) {
    var store = getObjectStore(DB_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
    var req = store.clear();
    req.onsuccess = function(evt) {
      displayActionSuccess("Store cleared");
      displayPubList(store);
    };
    req.onerror = function (evt) {
      console.error("clearObjectStore:", evt.target.errorCode);
      displayActionFailure(this.error);
    };
  }
```